# Blogdown: Deploy with Netlify fails with standard theme

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown, netlify

I just installed a new RStudio project with blogdown + standard theme from scratch and deployed it via GitHub to Netlify.  A process which worked all the time with older versions of hugo-lithium-theme. But now it does not deploy. I changed nothing at all: just installed and pushed it via my [GitHub-repo](https://github.com/petzi53/test-blogdown-new) to Netlify

The last few lines with error message were:

```
10:03:08 PM: Build complete: exit code: 0
10:03:08 PM: Cleaning up docker container 
10:03:08 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'publish' 
10:03:08 PM: Deploying to CDN 10:03:09 PM: Failed to deploy publish to CDN 
10:03:09 PM: stat /mnt/build-work/buildbot-796257821/repo/publish: no such file or directory 
10:03:09 PM: Finished processing build request in 16.651393261s
```

I was using HUGO_VERSION 0.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update]** I just noticed this line in the error log:

```
10:03:08 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'publish'
```

You probably specified a wrong folder name for the publish directory. The default for Hugo is `public` instead of `publish`. See [Section 3.1 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/netlify.html) for some sample settings.

---

Occasionally Netlify fails to build a site (for reasons that I don't understand), and you can try to click the "Trigger deploy" button in the "Deploys" tab on https://app.netlify.com if you want to redeploy the master branch of your repo:

[image: Trigger deploy]

Or click the specific failed deploy then click the "Retry deploy" button:

[image: Retry deploy]

Comment: Thanks, I know this and did "Trigger deploy" and/or "Retry deploy" several times. To be sure another try today. I post the last few lines with the error messages in my question. (I used 0.27). [ I'm sorry that I had in the last view days so may problems and keeping you busy all the time.]

Comment: oh no! I am embarrassed! Sorry!

Comment: It happens. Our eyes are not always sharp. Sometimes you need an additional pair of eyes :)